# incorrect time on macOS 11.2

Tags: macos, time

Currently, I have updated my system to macos big sur and am facing a problem with incorrect time. Although i have encountered this problem early in Mojave time, i  tried to use sudo sntp command to force the system to synchronize time with sntp servers and i wrote a crontab command to make it synchronize every hour. However, when it comes to macos big sur, a timed process is replacing ntp service. I found that everytime i restart this process, the time will be forced to update. i wanna ask is there a way to make the system automatically kill and restart the process timed so i can keep my time always right?

Comment: What process are you killing - how do you know the time is wrong?

Comment: im killing timed process. i know because i check it with time.is website

Comment: How far out are the times - It might help to show actual terminal output

Comment: thx how to show terminal output?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414088/macos-timed-wont-keep-accurate-time and some of the comments. No answer yet but possible solution from macrumors.