# MacOS timed won't keep accurate time

Tags: macos, time, clock

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports, 16GB) running Big Sur 11.1 won't keep accurate time. It's regularly up to a minute off. I verified this using:

- https://time.gov
- Comparison with my iPhone
- `sudo sntp -d time.apple.com`

I've tried `sntp -sS time.apple.com`, and it doesn't adjust the time. I'd expect it to step to the right time, given we're (way!) more than 50ms off.

I've tried turning off automatic time sync in the system preferences, then setting the time right by hand, then turning automatic sync back on and *it puts the clock back to the wrong time!*

I've tried killing `timed` - it's restarted and the time remains wrong.

I've tried removing `/var/db/timed/com.apple.timed.plist` and then restarting `timed`. It recreates the file and the time remains wrong.

Reading [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-is-keeping-the-clock-updated-properly/117865), I checked the contents of the plist file, but mine doesn't appear to have any store of the current offset:

```
# plutil -p com.apple.timed.plist
{
  "BootUUID" => "<redacted>"
  "HostUUID" => "<redacted>"
  "RTCResetCount" => 0
  "TMLastNtpFetchAttempt" => 5331203.310338818
  "TMLastRtcTime" => 5331203.336288487
  "TMSystemTimeSet" => 0
  "TMTimeSynthesizer" => {length = 499, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 00000179 }
  "TMVersionKey" => 17
}
```

No mention of `TMLastSystemTime` or `TMTimeError`.

I'm at my wits end with this. It's a real problem because it often prevents me using 1Password-generated TOTP codes because the drift is so bad.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Have you tried a different nntp server? There are a few to choose from in the control panel or you can add one of your choice.

Comment: Pretty sure Apple's time servers aren't 47 seconds out! LOL But yes, `sntp -d` confirms that the time is off - it just won't fix it.

Comment: [In your confirmation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57114434#57114434) - what do you see in place of this (towards the end of the output) `ipaddr:         17.253.24.125
-0.007032 +/- 0.000137 time.apple.com 17.253.24.125
`

Comment: You are not alone, though my Mac's time is correct. Big Sur seems to have introduced some time problems.  See https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/time-synchronization-command-line-in-macos-big-sur.2279396/ which is about the time being wrong after wake from sleep and remaining wrong.  But no solution.

Comment: @brmike: `ipaddr:         17.253.34.125 +21.635102 +/- 0.000153 time.apple.com 17.253.34.125` and `https://time.gov/` confirms I'm about 21 seconds behind right now.

Comment: The solution may well be to use Chrony. See latest post in the macrumors thread.

Comment: I'm running Big Sur on my new iMac and it agrees to the second with https://time.gov.

Comment: @Natsfan My iMac is now keeping time to the millisecond or better.  I don't really need that (some people do), but it is nice to have!

Answer (score 7):

There are other reports saying that time under Big Sur is not as accurate as it used to be, does not fully correct the time and in some cases maybe in error by many seconds. For example [Time Synchronization Command line in MacOS Big Sur](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/time-synchronization-command-line-in-macos-big-sur.2279396/)

In my case (2019 iMac) the time *was* consistently about 60 to 70 mS fast.

A simple command line check is to use the terminal command `sntp pool.ntp.org`. For examples:

```
sntp pool.ntp.org
+0.000444 +/- 0.084480 pool.ntp.org 129.250.35.250

sntp time.apple.com
+0.000304 +/- 0.000214 time.apple.com 17.253.66.125
```

This result is showing what my iMac now achieves - the first number shows an error of less than 1 mS.

To achieve this accuracy Apple's `timed` daemon needs to be replaced.

The cross-platform app for this is [Chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org). This can be installed easily via Homebrew but its configuration might be considered as something of a black art.  Much easier is to use [ChronyControl](https://www.whatroute.net/chronycontrol.html).  Just download, unzip and drag the app to /Applications.

With SIP disabled (if only temporarily) you can disable Apple's `timed` using:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.timed.plist
```

But don't worry if you want SIP enabled at all times, the `timed` daemon uses very little resources and ChronyControl will prevent it making time changes.

The first time you run ChronyControl, it will configure everything for you including starting the `chronyd` daemon with a default configuration, configuring logs and starting a helpful GUI app. Here is the GUI:

[image: ChronyControl's GUI]

and the tracking display:

[image: Graphical tracking window]

The only change I have made to the configuration is to replace the use of general purpose servers `pool.ntp.org` with a country specific set of servers `au.pool.ntp.org`.

The only other thing you might want to change is that ChronyControl puts the configuration file in `/etc/chrony.d`. Better, perhaps, to put it in `/usr/local/etc/chrony.d`.

Chrony is open source (and free), ChronyControl is donation-ware ($15 suggested) and its from the developer of the long established WhatRoute network utility.

I got started on using Chrony as a result of [Feek's](https://forums.macrumors.com/members/feek.380557/) post on MacRumors to whom I give full credit for the discovery.